# Not work: CSS media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make responsive design website.
But now, I have one trouble.

CSS property configured in media query(break point: 768px) does not apply proper HTML element. CSS property in not media query(e.g. font-family in body) does work.
[verification img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTTbw.png)

Code is here.

```css
@charset "UTF-8"
/*レスポンシブ用(ブレークポイント 768px)*/

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /*
------------------
ヘッダー
------------------
*/
  #main_stage div h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #main_stage div img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*
------------------
フッター
------------------
*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript本格入門</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="main_stage">
    <div>
      <h1>Responsive</h1>
      <img src="media/DSCF0959.JPG">
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to apply CSS property to HTML element.

How do I solve this problem?

**Information**
browser: Google Chrome(latest ver)
Vertial Box(latest ver)
CentOS 6.9

Comment: Did you put the path correctly at the link tag? Try to make the h1 bigger outside mediaquery and see if it works

Comment: @masterjohn12 You're right. I made the h1 outside mediaquery, and then it have worked! But, why does not work CSS property in mediaquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replace css code:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #main_stage div h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #main_stage div img {
      width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are messing semicolon after: `@charset "UTF-8";`

Comment: It's my fault. I added semicolon after there, CSS does work. Thank you very much!!!